# Create Spinner and Adapter without any XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I can create a very simple `Spinner` with code like this

```
    final List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add("First");
    categories.add("Second");
    categories.add("Third");

    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.spinner, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

however, this requires `R.layout.spinner` in my app. How can I avoid this XML with own, pure Java code, e.g. by implementing an own `ArrayAdapter`-like class?

Answer (score 1):

Extend you custom adapter from *ArrayAdapter* and try to override `getView()` with your own code. You should be able to create the adapter with a null resource id. You will have to build you own views since you will no longer be using a resource.